# iOS app submission - Invalid Binary

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, submission

I tried to submit my app thrice,every time it just failed,mailing me the same thing again n again

> The signature for your app bundle contains entitlement values that are not supported. 
>       For   the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement, the first value
>       in the array must consist of the prefix provided by Apple in the provisioning profile 
>       followed by a bundle identifier suffix. The bundle identifier must match the bundle
>       identifier for one of your apps or another app that you are permitted to use as the iCloud container identifier.
>
> Specifically, value "TXVNxxxxxx.*" for key "com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-
>       identifiers" in `Gamer5` is not supported.

what should exactly be my bundle identifier currently it is `com.Mycompany.Gamer5`
 is it necessary to have exactly matching names while creating the app in itunes connect account and the project name and in my .plist bundle identifier(`com.Mycompany.Gamer5`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem was in my app id i had iCloud enabled.which was not supported from my app so from my App Id i just unchecked the Box that says **Enable iCloud** and resubmitted the app

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the following:

1. Have you gone in to the [provisioning portal](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) and set up an App ID. If so you will have made a bundle identifier which should match what you have in you Xcode project (check its correct in the info.plist file too).
2. In the provisioning portal also make sure you created a provisioning profile for your app (make sure this is for distribution). Download that and double click it to install it in Xcode.
3. The bundle identifier you used in iTunes connect should also match up with the one used for your App ID (mentioned above) and the one used in the Xcode project. Consistency across the board is what you are aiming for!

Comment: the problem was in my app id i had iCloud enabled.which was not supported from my app so from my App Id i just unchecked the Box that says **Enable iClod** and resubmitted the app